# How can I get Perl Package name from Perl Module Location

Tags: perl

Code below will find the path of Perl Modules and store it in @files array. 
I tried a regexp of removing @INC path from the perl module path, but it didn't work.
Please let me know a better way to get a Perl Module name from the Module path given.

```
#Get locally installed Perl module path
my @files = ();
find({
    wanted => sub {
            push @files, $File::Find::fullname
              if defined $File::Find::fullname && -f $File::Find::fullname && /\.pm$/
        },
    follow => 1,
    follow_skip => 2,
}, @INC);

# Make the hash with Perl Module Path and Perl Module Name
my ($file_path, $name) = ("", "");
my %modules = ();
foreach $file_path (@files) { #loop through all the perl module (.pms) found
    for (@INC) {#replace the path with scope resolution operator
        if ($_ !~ /^\.$/) {
            if ($file_path =~ /$_/) {
                ($name = $file_path) =~ s/$_//g;
                $name =~ s/\//::/g;
                $name =~ s/\.pm$//g;
                $modules{$file_path} = $name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a module that's already been loaded via a standard `use` statement, then the best way might be to do something like:

```
my %CNI = reverse %INC;
my $module = $CNI{$filename};
$module =~ s{[.]pmc?$}{};
$module =~ s{/}{::}g;
```

In the general case, try [Module::Metadata](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Metadata) - this scans a module's source code and finds `package` statements inside it. Module::Metadata has been bundled with Perl since Perl 5.14.

Comment: for packages like DBIx::Class::Carp, Module::Metadata doesn't print the package info as the package information is missing in the module. Is there anyway that I can get the Package Name for them as well?

Comment: Ultimately you just have to accept that there isn't a one-to-one correspondence between modules and packages, and that no solution will be perfect. A module can define one package, or multiple packages, or no packages. Conversely, a package definition could be split over multiple modules, which all need to be loaded for the package to be considered "complete".